# How to make dashboard without tabbar and inner screens with tabbar in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, dashboard

I want to make an app with one dashboard and some inner screens. I want to include all main screen in dashboard. Therefore I don't want to include dashboard on tabbar. But I want to add the inner main screen on tab bar so that user can move from one screen to another screen without going to dashboard. Also user have options to go on dashboard.

Please suggest any solution for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by below steps:

Take one "TabBar" based application.
Take one "UINavigationController" object in App Delegate.

Now,
Take your DashBoard View Controller and add it into NavigationController object like below:

```
////Add DashBoard View////
DashBoardViewController *objDashBoardViewController = [[DashBoardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashBoardViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objDashBoardViewController];
[nc setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
self.navController = nc;
[nc release];
```

Do the above thing in below method of AppDelegate Class.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
}
```

Now, when user will click on any button of DashBoard then you can call the TabBar object. So that, user will navigate from DashBoard to TabBar based application.

```
[self.navController pushViewController:self.objTabBar animated:YES];
```

Hope, you have got idea.

Cheers and start with Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got this error. Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x6d86f80>. On this line [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES];
Please suggest.

Comment: Make sure, you have synthesize the "tabBarController" and it's IBOutlet. And then you have added view controllers into TabBar.

Comment: Yes I have done this in AppDelegate